# Program does not stop

Tags: development-environment, dev-c++

I'm trying to create a guessing game where you can play as many times as you want before exiting. The issue I'm having currently is this program does not stop. If you put the correct answer it will just keep saying "Match" for days on end. Same if you get it incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    char name[10][20]= {"DUMBO","MICKEY MOUSE","GOOFY","DONALD DUCK"};
    char charName[20];
    int count, nameMatch;
    char found;

    printf("Enter the name of a Disney cartoon character ");
    gets(charName);
    strupr (charName);
    found = 'n';

    for (count=0;count<4;count++)
    { if(!strcmp(charName, name[count]))
        {found = 'y';}
    }
    while (nameMatch == 0)

    if(found == 'y')
        puts("Match");
        else
        puts("No Match");

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `gets`: get rid of this before doing anything else.

Comment: Also, fix your indentation; the actual syntax of your code does not match the way you've indented it.  That is likely part of your problem.

Comment: And think about your `while` loop: there is nothing in the body of the loop that would allow `nameMatch` or `found` to actually change.

Comment: all previous comments plus don't assume initialisation of `nameMatch` - be explicit